# Fill of a thermometer

Tags: tikz-pgf

The objective here is to create a fill of the thermometer to a desired degree being this in Celsius or Fahrenheit. Of course optimizations in the code below are welcomed like how I create the labels or the diagram itself. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.5pt, x=0.5pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\path[draw=black,fill=white,miter limit=4,even odd rule,line width=2.5pt,fill=gray!20]
  (280.0313,169.3125) .. controls (263.9888,169.3125) and (250.6461,179.3446) ..
  (247.8125,192.5625) -- 
  (247.3438,563.7500) .. controls (235.7346,573.2243) and (228.3438,587.6282) ..
  (228.3438,603.7813) .. controls (228.3438,632.3161) and (251.4651,655.4688) ..
  (280.0000,655.4688) .. controls (308.5349,655.4688) and (331.6563,632.3161) ..
  (331.6563,603.7813) .. controls (331.6563,587.6282) and (324.2654,573.2243) ..
  (312.6563,563.7500) -- 
  (312.2500,192.5625) .. controls 
  (309.4164,179.3446) and (296.0737,169.3125) .. (280.0313,169.3125) -- cycle;
\foreach \y/\x in {190/100,
                   227/90,
                   264/80,
                   301/70,
                   338/60,
                   375/50,
                   412/40,
                   449/30,
                   486/20,
                   523/10,
                   560/0%
                   }
    {
    \draw (210,\y)--(190,\y) node[left](\x){\x\textdegree C~};
    }
\foreach \u/\v in {189.999/212,
                   231.111/192,
                   272.222/172,
                   313.333/152,
                   354.444/132,
                   395.555/112,
                   436.666/92,
                   477.777/72,
                   518.888/52,
                   559.999/32%
                   }
    {
    \draw (350,\u)--(370,\u) node[right](\v){\v\textdegree F};
    }
\draw (200,190)node[yshift=4ex, OrangeRed] {Celsius} --(200,560) ;  
\draw (360,190)node[yshift=4ex, Cerulean] {Fahrenheit}--(360,560);
\draw node[xshift=-5em, OrangeRed] at (100) {Water boils};
\draw node[xshift=5em, Cerulean] at (212) {Water boils};
\draw node[xshift=-5em, OrangeRed] at (0) {Water freezes};
\draw node[xshift=5em, Cerulean] at (32) {Water freezes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a sample out of the above code:

[image]

Comment: At a very elementary level, [`ifsym`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ifsym) provides `\Thermo{0}`...`\Thermo{6}` that are between 0/6
and 6/6 full of mercury.

Comment: For the clipping of the thermometer `\draw (120:5mm) arc (-220:40:0.5cm) --++(0,5cm) arc (0:180:{3.75mm}) --cycle;` might be enough (the top arc needs some computation :P)

Comment: A simple thermometer like this could be drawn by a two lines and two arcs, can’t it? Either way, you can draw the thermometer after the nodes and then use its `path picture` (which is like a `clip` but behind the `draw`n lines) and the created nodes (they are named) to fill the area. Instead of the created nodes, the path itself (or `calc` can be used).

Comment: I think this should be posted on [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I thought so but I was unable to do it.  Can you provide a sample of a path with the same shape or similar shape done with two lines and two arcs?

Comment: @azetina Have you seen my other answer with the keys and the `insert path` style? That consists only of the lower arc (angle initially 270), a line upwards (of length `height`), the upper arc (angle initially 180, from the looks of it, this is not the same as in your example) and a `-- cycle`, i.e. a line downwards. Both solutions being based on `path picture` won’t work if you rotate something (the `path picture bounding box` is always in the canvas plane).

Answer (score 19):

The easiest way:

1. Draw the nodes of the scales.
2. Draw/fill the thermometer.
3. Use the `path picture` and the declared nodes to fill the lower part of the thermometer.

For 53 °C you can use

```
\path (C0) -- (C100) coordinate[pos=.53] (@aux);
\fill[red] (@aux) rectangle (path picture bounding box.south east);
```

For the Fahrenheit scale you can use the same but need to to calculate the position beforehand (a not pictured coordinate at 0 °F might help).

Other than that, improvements would be:

- A shape that does exactly this with well-defined anchors which can be used to place the scales. (I think implementing the scales could result in a big job as one can draw the scales in very different styles.)
- The same as above but in TikZ and not PGF (not a shape but a `insert path` with a few options that defines a few coordinates (“anchors”) that can be used to draw the scales.

### Code

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass[letterpaper,tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier}
\tikzset{
  thermometer/.style={insert path={
    (280.0313,169.3125) .. controls (263.9888,169.3125) and (250.6461,179.3446) ..
    (247.8125,192.5625) -- 
    (247.3438,563.7500) .. controls (235.7346,573.2243) and (228.3438,587.6282) ..
    (228.3438,603.7813) .. controls (228.3438,632.3161) and (251.4651,655.4688) ..
    (280.0000,655.4688) .. controls (308.5349,655.4688) and (331.6563,632.3161) ..
    (331.6563,603.7813) .. controls (331.6563,587.6282) and (324.2654,573.2243) ..
    (312.6563,563.7500) -- 
    (312.2500,192.5625) .. controls 
    (309.4164,179.3446) and (296.0737,169.3125) .. (280.0313,169.3125) -- cycle
}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.5pt, x=0.5pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\foreach \y/\x in {190/100,227/90,264/80,301/70,338/60,375/50,412/40,449/30,486/20,523/10,560/0}
  \draw (210,\y)--(190,\y) node[left](C\x){\x\textdegree C~};
\foreach \u/\v in {189.999/212,231.111/192,272.222/172,313.333/152,354.444/132,395.555/112,436.666/92,477.777/72,518.888/52,559.999/32}
    \draw (350,\u)--(370,\u) node[right](F\v){\v\textdegree F};

\path[draw=black,fill=white,miter limit=4,even odd rule,line width=2.5pt,fill=gray!20]
   [thermometer][path picture={\fill[red] (C40) rectangle (path picture bounding box.south east);}];
\draw (200,190)node[yshift=4ex, OrangeRed] {Celsius} --(200,560) ;  
\draw (360,190)node[yshift=4ex, Cerulean] {Fahrenheit}--(360,560);
\draw node[xshift=-5em, OrangeRed] at (C100) {Water boils};
\draw node[xshift=5em, Cerulean] at (F212) {Water boils};
\draw node[xshift=-5em, OrangeRed] at (C0) {Water freezes};
\draw node[xshift=5em, Cerulean] at (F32) {Water freezes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: The shape would be very similar to the `rounded rectangle` shape.

Comment: I suppose this fills the curve at the top of the thermometer smoothly, right?

Comment: @azetina It does for values above 100 °C, e.g. `\path (C0) -- (C100) coordinate[pos=1.1] (@aux);`. Or what do you mean? I fear I can’t follow you completely. If fills as smooth as it does for the lower arc of the thermometer …

Answer (score 19):

This is the closest to a shape. It is a `insert path` solution which uses values from keys.

Hopefully they are self-explanatory.

The `scale name` key is added so that the last drawn thermometer has a name independent of the  `name` key. (Say if you draw a few thermometers. If you want to add a scale, you most likely want to use this on a different path so that you won’t end up with the same draw lines (although this could be avoided with a `edge` as I just realize).)

If you want to add more “anchors” than the four corners you will need to add `coordinate`s.

You can play with the angle values a little bit to see what they do (shouldn’t be any surprises, just don’t use zero or very big values (although zero should be catched)).

The scales are only called `left` and `right` to generalize the approach.

The center of the bottom circle is placed at the last path coordinate (in our cases this is `(0,0)`).

Given the implementation `tm scale` one could easily write a `\foreach` loop that works with given values instead of calculated same-sized values.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier,siunitx}
\definecolor{coldblue}{cmyk}{0.321 0.004 0 0.047}
\definecolor{hotred}{cmyk}{0 0.89 .80 .19}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  declare function={
    celsiusToFahrenheit(\pgf@temp)=\pgf@temp*1.8+32;
    fahrenheitToCelsius(\pgf@temp)=(\pgf@temp-32)/1.8;
  },
  thermometer/name/.initial=tm,
  thermometer/height/.initial=+4cm,
  thermometer/width/.initial=+1cm,
  thermometer/top angle/.initial=180,
  thermometer/bottom angle/.initial=270,
  thermometer/top left/.initial=100,
  thermometer/bottom left/.initial=0,
  thermometer/top right/.initial={celsiusToFahrenheit(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/top left})},
  thermometer/bottom right/.initial={celsiusToFahrenheit(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/bottom left})},
  thermometer/left steps/.initial=10,
  thermometer/right steps/.initial=9,
  thermometer/scale distance/.initial=+.5cm,
  thermometer/scale name/.initial=tm@tm,
  thermometer/.search also={/tikz},
  thermometer/.code={\pgfqkeys{/tikz/thermometer}{#1}},
  Thermometer/.style={
    insert path={{%
      [thermometer={#1}]
      [/utils/exec=%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\tikz@tm@halfwidth{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/width})/2}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@tm@bottomaux{180-.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/bottom angle})}%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\tikz@tm@bottomradius{\tikz@tm@halfwidth/(sin(\tikz@tm@bottomaux))}%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@tm@topaux{180-.5*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/top angle})}%
      \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\tikz@tm@topradius{\tikz@tm@halfwidth/(sin(\tikz@tm@topaux))}%
      ]
      ++ (90+\tikz@tm@bottomaux:\tikz@tm@bottomradius)
        coordinate[alias=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-bottom left] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/name}-bottom left)
      arc [start angle=90+\tikz@tm@bottomaux, delta angle={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/bottom angle}}, radius=+\tikz@tm@bottomradius]
        coordinate[alias=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-bottom right] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/name}-bottom right)
      -- ++ (+90:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/height})
        coordinate[alias=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-top right] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/name}-top right)
      arc [start angle=-90+\tikz@tm@topaux, delta angle={\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/top angle}}, radius=+\tikz@tm@topradius]
        coordinate[alias=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-top left] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/name}-top left)
      -- cycle
  }}},
  tm scale/.style 2 args={
    insert path={{
      [thermometer={#2}]
      ([shift={(#1:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale distance})}] \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-bottom #1) --
      ([shift={(#1:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale distance})}] \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-top #1)
      \foreach \tikz@tm@scale[
        evaluate={\tikz@tm@pos=\tikz@tm@scale/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/#1 steps})},
        evaluate={\tikz@tm@value=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/bottom #1}+\tikz@tm@pos*(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/top #1}-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/bottom #1}))}
      ] in {0,...,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/#1 steps}} {
        node[pos/.expanded=\tikz@tm@pos, tm scale #1/.expanded={\tikz@tm@value}] {}
      }
    }}
  },
  tm fill/.style args={#1#2:[#3]#4}{% #1 shouln’t be a comma, #2 is cheating, #3 are options (mandatory), #4 is the value
                                    % may as well some other keys ... meh :|
    /utils/exec={%
      \if#1l
        \def\pgf@tempa{east}%
        \def\pgf@tempb{west}%
      \else
        \def\pgf@tempa{west}%
        \def\pgf@tempb{east}%
      \fi
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tikt@tm@pos{#4/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/top #1#2}-(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/bottom #1#2}))}},
    path picture={
      \path (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-bottom #1#2 -| path picture bounding box.south \pgf@tempb) --
            (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/thermometer/scale name}-top #1#2 -| path picture bounding box.south \pgf@tempb) coordinate[pos/.expanded=\tikt@tm@pos, name=tm@aux];
      \fill [style/.expanded={#3}] (path picture bounding box.south \pgf@tempa) rectangle (tm@aux);
    }
  }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{% The \csname l__siunitx_unit_product_tl\endcsname is ugly. :(
  tm scale left/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    draw,
    inner sep=+0pt,
    minimum height=+0pt,
    minimum width=+10pt,
    label={left:{\tablenum[table-format=3.0,table-auto-round]{#1}\csname l__siunitx_unit_product_tl\endcsname\si{\celsius}}}
  },
  tm scale right/.style={
    shape=rectangle,
    draw,
    inner sep=+0pt,
    minimum height=+0pt,
    minimum width=+10pt,
    label={right:{\tablenum[table-format=3.0,table-auto-round]{#1}\csname l__siunitx_unit_product_tl\endcsname\si{\degree F}}}
  }
}
\begin{document}
\foreach \CELSIUS[evaluate={\CELSIUSCOLOR=min(\CELSIUS,100)}] in {0,5,...,120}{% Careful, will typeset 25 pages!
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [draw=black,line width=2.5pt,fill=gray!20]
      [Thermometer]
      [tm fill={left:[hotred!\CELSIUSCOLOR!coldblue]\CELSIUS}];
\draw [tm scale={left}{}]
      [tm scale={right}{}];
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: I love the animation! `:)` *very cold cold cold cold cool cool average average hot hot hot HOT HOT OMG IT BURNS SO MUCH!* `❤`

Answer (score 13):

Here is an attempt that first defines the path as macro which is first use to fill the whole thermometer, then to clip the liquid filling of the thermometer and finally to draw the outline. You can change the fluid level by changing the line `\def\tempincelsius{55}`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.5pt, x=0.5pt,yscale=-1, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
\def\thermopath{
  (280.0313,169.3125) .. controls (263.9888,169.3125) and (250.6461,179.3446) ..
  (247.8125,192.5625) -- 
  (247.3438,563.7500) .. controls (235.7346,573.2243) and (228.3438,587.6282) ..
  (228.3438,603.7813) .. controls (228.3438,632.3161) and (251.4651,655.4688) ..
  (280.0000,655.4688) .. controls (308.5349,655.4688) and (331.6563,632.3161) ..
  (331.6563,603.7813) .. controls (331.6563,587.6282) and (324.2654,573.2243) ..
  (312.6563,563.7500) -- 
  (312.2500,192.5625) .. controls 
  (309.4164,179.3446) and (296.0737,169.3125) .. (280.0313,169.3125) -- cycle
 }
\path[miter limit=4,even odd rule,fill=gray!20]
    \thermopath;

\def\tempincelsius{55}
\begin{scope}
    \clip \thermopath;
    \fill[red] (210,{560- 3.7*\tempincelsius}) -- ++(140,0)
        -- (350, 690) -- (210, 690) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\path[draw=black,miter limit=4,even odd rule,line width=2.5pt]
    \thermopath;

\foreach \y/\x in {190/100,
                   227/90,
                   264/80,
                   301/70,
                   338/60,
                   375/50,
                   412/40,
                   449/30,
                   486/20,
                   523/10,
                   560/0%
                   }
    {
    \draw (210,\y)--(190,\y) node[left](\x){\x\textdegree C~};
    }
\foreach \u/\v in {189.999/212,
                   231.111/192,
                   272.222/172,
                   313.333/152,
                   354.444/132,
                   395.555/112,
                   436.666/92,
                   477.777/72,
                   518.888/52,
                   559.999/32%
                   }
    {
    \draw (350,\u)--(370,\u) node[right](\v){\v\textdegree F};
    }
\draw (200,190)node[yshift=4ex, OrangeRed] {Celsius} --(200,560) ;  
\draw (360,190)node[yshift=4ex, Cerulean] {Fahrenheit}--(360,560);
\draw node[xshift=-5em, OrangeRed] at (100) {Water boils};
\draw node[xshift=5em, Cerulean] at (212) {Water boils};
\draw node[xshift=-5em, OrangeRed] at (0) {Water freezes};
\draw node[xshift=5em, Cerulean] at (32) {Water freezes};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice coding. I will look into it.

Answer (score 13):

Not adding much in terms of appearance or customization, but by delving into some (undocumented) features of the mathematical engine it is possible to add postfix operators `c` and `f` which scale their calculations over a pre-specified `\thermometerlength`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfmathdeclareoperator{f}{fahrenheit}{1}{postfix}{600}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{fahrenheit}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfmathparse{int((#1-32)/1.8)*\thermometerlength/100}%
        \expandafter%
    \endgroup\expandafter\edef\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
}
\pgfmathdeclareoperator{c}{celcius}{1}{postfix}{600}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{celcius}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfmathparse{#1*\thermometerlength/100}%
        \expandafter%
    \endgroup\expandafter\edef\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\def\thermometerlength{5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    temperature/.style={
        insert path={
            (cos 50, 0) arc(50:-230:1) -- ++(0,#1) -- ++(2*cos 50,0) -- cycle
        }
    }]

\draw  (-1.5, 0) -- +(0, 100c);
\foreach \c in {0,10,...,100}
    \draw (-1.5,\c c) +(0.25, 0) -- +(-0.25,0) node [left] {\c$^\circ$ C};

\draw  (1.5, 0) -- +(0, 212f);
\foreach \f in {32,52,...,212}
    \draw (1.5,\f f)  +(-0.25, 0) -- +(0.25,0) node [right] {\f$^\circ$ F};

\fill [red!75, temperature=55c];

\draw [ultra thick] 
    (cos 50, 0) arc(50:-230:1) -- ++(0, 100c) arc (180:0:cos 50) -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for showing this: it is absolutely nice!