# TikZ: fill a glass tube with red color

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there a way to fill this glass tube with different quantities of red color?
I'm looking for a similar solution found in the thermometer problem ([Fill of a thermometer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124144/fill-of-a-thermometer)).

My minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and .5);
\draw (-1,0)--(-1,-5);
\draw (1,0)--(1,-5);
\draw (-1,-5) arc (180:360:1);

\foreach \y/\x in {-5/1,
                   -4/2,
                   -3/3,
                   -2/4%
                   }
    {
    \draw (-0.2,\y)--(0.2,\y) node[right](\x){\x};

    \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
                    {\draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$)--($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);}
    };


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 30):

A little make-up with slight modifications

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[left color=red,right color=red!40] 
    (-1,-2)--(-1,-5) arc (180:360:1)  -- (1,-2) arc (0:180:1 and 0.3);
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and .3);
\draw (-1,0)--(-1,-5) arc (180:360:1) --(1,-5) -- (1,0);
\draw[red!90!black!70] (0,-2) ellipse (1 and .3);

\foreach \y/\x in {-5/1,-4/2,-3/3,-2/4}
    {
    \draw (-0.2,\y) to[bend right=10](0.2,\y) node[right,yslant=0.15](\x){\x};

    \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
       \draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$)to[bend right=5]($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: too lazy for surface tension and colorblind for the surface edge

Comment: I want to draw two identical tubes like this with different level of solutions for a math problem illustration. The volume marking would be 300 ml, 600 l, and 900 ml. How can I add one more copy of the tube to the right?

Answer (score 19):

With adjustable height:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}    

\begin{document}
\newlength{\mylen}
\setlength{\mylen}{-3cm}                %% change here for changing length (height)
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and .5);
\draw (-1,0)--(-1,-5);
\draw (1,0)--(1,-5);
\draw (-1,-5) arc (180:360:1);

\fill[red!50] (-1,\mylen)--(-1,-5) arc (180:360:1) -- (1,\mylen) --cycle;
\path[fill=red!40!white,] (0,\mylen) ellipse (1 and .5);       

\foreach \y/\x in {-5/1,
                   -4/2,
                   -3/3,
                   -2/4%
                   }
    {
    \draw (-0.2,\y)--(0.2,\y) node[right](\x){\x};

    \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
                    {\draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$)--($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);}
    };


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Obligatory animation:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\foreach \h in {-1.2,-1.4,...,-5}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and .3);
\draw (-1,0)--(-1,-5);
\draw (1,0)--(1,-5);
\draw (-1,-5) arc (180:360:1);

\fill[red!50] (-1,\h)--(-1,-5) arc (180:360:1) -- (1,\h) --cycle;
\path[fill=red!40!white,] (0,\h) ellipse (1 and .3);

\foreach \y/\x in {-5/1,
                   -4/2,
                   -3/3,
                   -2/4%
                   }
    {
    \draw (-0.2,\y)--(0.2,\y) node[right](\x){\x};

    \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
                    {\draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$)--($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);}
    };


\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Two separate solutions.

## Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \fill[color=red!80] (-1,-4) arc (180:0:1 and .2) -- (1,-5) arc (0:-180:1);
        \fill[color=red] (0,-4) ellipse (1 and .2);%Not necessary, it is there if the opacity is changed or a solution deleted ;)
        \fill[color=red!35] (-1,-2) arc (180:0:1 and .2) -- (1,-4) arc (0:-180:1 and .2);
        \fill[color=red!50] (0,-2) ellipse (1 and .2);
        \foreach \y/\x in {-5/1,-4/2,-3/3,-2/4}{%
            \draw (-0.2,\y) -- (0.2,\y) node[right](\x){\x};
            \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
               \draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$) -- ($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);
        };
        \draw[thick] (1,0) -- (1,-5) arc (0:-180:1) -- (-1,0);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) ellipse (1 and .2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Joining late the party (the right occasion to use `\pgfmathdeclareoperator`).

Key aspects of the answer:

1. drawing the glass tube is simpler at user-side as all the relevant code has been gathered by the `glass tube` style; options have been introduced to customize size of the tube; the scale is shown accordingly to customization provided;
2. added upper tick value to the indicators;
3. possibility to select the amount of liquid providing a ml-based measure: `liquid=4ml`.

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\tikzset{glass tube height/.store in=\glasslength,
 glass tube height=5,
 glass tube width/.store in=\glasswidth,
 glass tube width=1,
 glass tube/.style={glass indicators,
   insert path={
    (-\glasswidth,0)--(-\glasswidth,-\glasslength)arc (180:360:\glasswidth)
    (\glasswidth,-\glasslength)--(\glasswidth,0)
    (0,0) ellipse (\glasswidth{} and .5\glasswidth)
   }
 },
 glass indicators/.code={
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xglasslength{\glasslength -1}
    \foreach \y[count=\x] in {-\glasslength,-\xglasslength,...,-1}
    {
    \draw (-0.2,\y)--(0.2,\y) node[right](\x){\x};
    \ifnum\y<-1
    \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
                    {\draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$)--($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);}
    \fi
    };
 },
 liquid color/.code={\tikzset{liquid n/.style={top color=#1!10,bottom color=#1},liquid u/.style={#1!13}}},
 liquid/.style={
   insert path={
   \pgfextra{
    \fill[liquid n](-\glasswidth,#1)--(-\glasswidth,-\glasslength)arc (180:360:\glasswidth)
    (\glasswidth,-\glasslength)--(\glasswidth,#1)--(-\glasswidth,#1);
    \fill[liquid u](0,#1) ellipse (\glasswidth{} and .5\glasswidth);
    }
   },
 }
}

% code by Mark Wibrow:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124177/13304
\pgfmathdeclareoperator{ml}{milliliters}{2}{postfix}{600}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{milliliters}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfmathparse{#1-1-\glasslength}%
        \expandafter%
    \endgroup\expandafter\edef\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[glass tube];

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[liquid color=red,liquid=4ml];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Animated version (with tube customization):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\tikzset{glass tube height/.store in=\glasslength,
 glass tube height=5,
 glass tube width/.store in=\glasswidth,
 glass tube width=1,
 glass tube/.style={glass indicators,
   insert path={
    (-\glasswidth,0)--(-\glasswidth,-\glasslength)arc (180:360:\glasswidth)
    (\glasswidth,-\glasslength)--(\glasswidth,0)
    (0,0) ellipse (\glasswidth{} and .5\glasswidth)
   }
 },
 glass indicators/.code={
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\xglasslength{\glasslength -1}
    \foreach \y[count=\x] in {-\glasslength,-\xglasslength,...,-1}
    {
    \draw (-0.2,\y)--(0.2,\y) node[right](\x){\x};
    \ifnum\y<-1
    \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
                    {\draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$)--($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);}
    \fi
    };
 },
 liquid color/.code={\tikzset{liquid n/.style={top color=#1!10,bottom color=#1},liquid u/.style={#1!13}}},
 liquid/.style={
   insert path={
   \pgfextra{
    \fill[liquid n](-\glasswidth,#1)--(-\glasswidth,-\glasslength)arc (180:360:\glasswidth)
    (\glasswidth,-\glasslength)--(\glasswidth,#1)--(-\glasswidth,#1);
    \fill[liquid u](0,#1) ellipse (\glasswidth{} and .5\glasswidth);
    }
   },
 }
}

% code by Mark Wibrow:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124177/13304
\pgfmathdeclareoperator{ml}{milliliters}{2}{postfix}{600}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{milliliters}{1}{%
    \begingroup%
        \pgfmathparse{#1-1-\glasslength}%
        \expandafter%
    \endgroup\expandafter\edef\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter{\pgfmathresult}%
}

\begin{document}

\foreach \level in {1,...,9}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[glass tube height=9,glass tube width=2]
\draw[glass tube];

\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\fill[liquid color=red,liquid=\level ml];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Solved

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (1 and .5);
\draw (-1,0)--(-1,-5) arc (180:360:1)--(1,0);

\foreach \y/\x in {-5/1,
                   -4/2,
                   -3/3,
                   -2/4%
                   }
    {
    \draw (-0.2,\y)--(0.2,\y) node[right](\x){\x};

    \foreach \z in {0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8}
                    {\draw ($(-0.1,\z) + (0,\y)$)--($(0.1,\z)+(0,\y)$);}
    };

\filldraw[fill opacity=0.5,fill=red](-1,-2)--(-1,-5) arc (180:360:1)--(1,-2);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding a meniscus: \filldraw[fill opacity=0.5,fill=red](-1,-2.2)--(-1,-5) arc (180:360:1)--(1,-2.2) to [out=200,in=340] (-1,-2.2);

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: it looks like you've used code from the answers to produce your answer. It's best to thank people for their time and energy by upvoting helpful answers- if one answer solved the problem, you can accept it by using the green check mark. Welcome to the site!

Comment: @Jorge: Using a different perspective for the top of the glass than for the surface of the liquid is really confusing. I would suggest you go with one of the other solutions, vote for all answers that you find helpful, and accept the most useful one.